# Making sense of Windows sql availability groups, failover cluster, and load balancer

Tags: sql-server, windows, failovercluster, availability-group

I am having issues with creating a failover cluster with an availabilty group.

I've made a windows failover cluster, and a sql availability group. I also have an azure load balancer with an IP address and a DNS name.

I am trying to follow this guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-availability-group-tutorial#create-a-database-on-the-first-sql-server)

I get to the Configure the Listener, add Client access point, and things fail from there.

Is the name here supposed to be the DNS name in the load balancer? Same for the IP? Or is it supposed to be another object in Active directory.

Steps 5 and 6 seem to conflict, Is the dependency supposed to be a resource or an IP?

If anyone have any advice, I would be appreciative.

I have been using the above guide trying to get things to work in GUI before changing this over to powershell code.

I suspect either there is something I am missing, or this is all the same IP address and dns name used.